# How to compare a date field with another date field plus a delta value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document :

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(0, "RUBR58qePxvfGqR7WjpkiQ=="), 
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2020-02-05T18:30:14.152+0000"), 
    "retention" : NumberInt(24)
}
```

I want to select all items where `creation_date + retention < NOW`

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this **aggregation** pipeline should do the trick:

```
[
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: [
        {
          $gt: [
            {
              $toDate: {
                $sum: [
                  {
                    $toLong: "$creation_date"
                  },
                  "$retention"
                ]
              }
            },
            new Date()
          ]
        },
        "$$PRUNE",
        "$$KEEP"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @loki I don't think so. In order to implement the given condition you'd have to be able to either subtract `$retention` from `new Date()` or `sum` it into `$creation_date`, and `find()` does not work with these operations.

Comment: @loki Of course you could still do it with a `forEach()` or with the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator, but methinks it's not nearly optimized as much and, frankly, more trouble than it's worth.